# Bootstrap toggle button not working on collapse

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 navbar functionality. The navbar is working fine when not collapsed but when the nabar collapses, the button is not at all working and not showing the menu option. I really dont understand what is causing this problem. I tried figuring it out but couldnt find any solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated. When I use computer path to refer the bootstrap files then toggle button is not working but when i use web address its working. Can anybody please help me on this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>
Jobs 4 U
</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javscript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javscript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.mt-top{
margin-top:75px;
}
.mt-top1{
    margin-top:325px;
}
.vertical-center-row{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.colht1{
height:100px;
border: 5px solid yellow;
}
.navbar-custom {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    color:#ffffff;
    border-radius:0;
    padding:10px;
}
.ht{
    height:300px;
}
h2,h3{
text-align: center;
}
sup{
    color:red;
}
.bck{
background-image: url('images/job_index.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
height:600px;

}
.abtpad{
    padding:5px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button> 
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Jobs 4u</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="aboutus.php">How it Works</a></li>
        <li class="">
        <a class="" href="JobSeeker.php">Jobseeker</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
        <a class="" href="Employer.php">Employer</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
        <a class="" href="contactus.php">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>



    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you've presented here. Have you verified that your paths to jQuery and Bootstrap are correct?

Comment: the path is correct

Comment: when i am using computer path the toggle button is not working but when i give web address its working please help

Comment: The solution is simple: The local path you are using is wrong.  Doublecheck that the hierarchy you're linking is right.  Are your bootstrap assets in a folder named `bootstrap` in subfolders named `css` and `js` ?  Is jQuery located in the same folder as your HTML file?